# Работа с DXF. Python (Сортировка координат от точки отсчета)

Tags: python, сортировка, координаты, autocad

Есть файл `DXF`, написал функцию, которая получает координаты каждой точки в таком формате:

```
[
     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0],
     [0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 15.0, 10.0, 0.0],
     [15.0, 10.0, 0.0, 15.0, 10.0, 5.0],
     [15.0, 10.0, 5.0, 15.0, 13.0, 5.0]
]
```

Код:

```
def getCoordinates(key):
    # Функция получает координаты XYZ, по ключу # "AcDbLine\n" - линия, "AcDbPoint\n" - точка
    ind = []
    CoordList = []
    for n, e in enumerate(ll):
        if key in e:
            ind.append(n)
    for sp in ind:
        a = ll[sp + 2:sp + 13]
        try:  # Если это линия, то взять координаты начальной и конечно точек
            CoordList.append([float(a[0]), float(a[2]), float(a[4]), float(a[6]), float(a[8]), float(a[10])])
        except:  # Если это точка, то взять координаты точки
            CoordList.append([float(a[0]), float(a[2]), float(a[4])])
    return CoordList
```

Также в этом файле указана точка, это точка, с которой необходимо начинать отсчет. Координаты точки тоже получил `[15.0, 13.0, 5.0]`

Попытался создать словарь типа `1:[координаты линии]` но удалось только получить линию, на которой стоит точка и то не корректно работает.

Вот код:

```
for num, el in enumerate(getCoordinates("AcDbLine\n")):
    try:
        point = getCoordinates("AcDbPoint\n")[0]  # Получает координаты точки для сравнения

    except IndexError:  # Если точка не найдена, прекратить дальнейшие действия
        print ("Точка отсчета не найдена")
        break

    if point == el[:3] or point == el[4:]:  #Если координаты точки совпадают с линией
        D[1] = [el, GetLength("AcDbLine\n", num)]  # Первая линия, которая совпадает с точкой имеет индекс 1
```

Суть проблемы это записать эти координаты таким образом, чтобы они шли друг за другом начиная от точки отсчета. Точка отсчета может стоять в любом месте, но на узлах соприкосновения двух отрезков.

Для большей наглядности нарисовал  рисунок. Красными цифрами указан порядок, который необходимо получить.

Может я все не правильно делаю и кто предложит решение более лучшее?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так в DXF выглядит точка

```
AcDbPoint
 10
15.0
 20
13.0
 30
5.0
  0
```

а так линия

```
AcDbLine
 10
15.0
 20
10.0
 30
5.0
 11
15.0
 21
13.0
 31
5.0
  0
```

Точка как отдельный элемент и ставится вручную точно также как рисуется линия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def to_my_dict():
    prev_point = getCoordinates("AcDbPoint\n")
    if prev_point:
        point = prev_point[0]
    else:
        return "Точка отсчета не найдена"
    my_dict = {}
    all_lines = getCoordinates("AcDbLine\n")
    count = 1
    line_count = len(all_lines)
    while line_count:
        for el in all_lines:
            if point == el[:3] or point == el[3:]:
                my_dict[count] = el  # линия, в которой есть точка 
                count += 1
                line_count -= 1

                if point == el[:3]:
                    point = el[3:]
                else:
                    point = el[:3]
    return my_dict

print(to_my_dict())
```

Возможно я не совсем правильно Вас понял, если это не то, что нужно - оставьте коментарий и поясните вопрос более детально

Comment: Немного не так. Функцией getCoordinates() я могу получить и линию ("AcDbLine\n") и точку (AcDbPoint\n). Точка как отдельный элемент. Получается я первым условием хотел сравнить координаты точки, с координатами линии и если одна линия совпадает с точкой, то присвоить ей ключ 1. Следующим этапом необходимо сравнить координаты линии (которая уже с ключом 1) с остальными линиями и если точка у второй линии совпадает с точкой в предыдущей линии, то присвоить ключ 2 и так пройтись по всем линиям... Да, D словарь, спасибо за замечание) Немного запутано, но надеюсь удалось немного понятней рассказать.

Comment: Отредактировал ответ, подставил ваши значения вроде работает, обратите внимание, что я заменяю точку следующей в линии, возможно я ошибаюсь

Comment: Да, все работает, спасибо!